# Custom metric in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

How many requests per minute I can send for each custom metric in CloudWatch?

p.s. I know for standard metrics is 1 per minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quote from section *Publishing Single Data Points* within the [Amazon CloudWatch Developer Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/publishingMetrics.html):

> Although you can publish data points with time stamps as granular as one-thousandth of a second, Amazon CloudWatch aggregates the data to a minimum granularity of one minute